# How can I add the nextcord.ui.UserSelect to the Class?

Tags: python, discord, interaction, nextcord

This is the Error:

```
Ignoring exception in view <DropdownView timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Dropdown placeholder='Wähle ein Thema für deine Supportanfrage' min_values=1 max_values=1 options=[<SelectOption label='Entbannungsantrag' value='1' description='Stelle einen Entbannungsantrag' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='umschlag_rot' id=1197931350917926993> default=False>, <SelectOption label='Benutzer melden' value='2' description='Melde einen Benutzer für unangemessenes Verhalten' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='umschlag_orange' id=1197933708322295961> default=False>, <SelectOption label='Allgemeiner Support' value='3' description='Hilfe bei allgemeinen Fragen zum Server' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='imageremovebgpreview1' id=1197933021270122577> default=False>, <SelectOption label='Partnerschaftsanfrage' value='4' description='Beantrage eine Partnerschaft mit unserem Server' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='umschlag_grn' id=1197938005499985960> default=False>, <SelectOption label='Fehler melden' value='5' description="Melde ein Fehler unserer Bot's oder unseres Server's" emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='umschlag_blau' id=1197938018498138162> default=False>, <SelectOption label='Teambewerbung' value='6' description='Bewerbe dich als Teammitglied' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='umschlag_lila' id=1202997159184830556> default=False>] disabled=False>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ui\view.py", line 375, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\Markus\PycharmProjects\Discord Bot\scr\main.py", line 503, in callback
    await interaction.response.send_modal(EntbannungsantragModal())
  File "C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\interactions.py", line 946, in send_modal
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\webhook\async_.py", line 197, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
nextcord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In data.components.1.components.0: Value of field "type" must be one of (4,).
```

This ist my Code:

```
class EntbannungsantragModal(discord.ui.Modal):
                    def __init__(self):
                        super().__init__(" | Entbannungsantrag")
                        self.entbannungsantrag_grund = discord.ui.TextInput(label= "Warum möchtest du entbannt werden?", min_length=0, max_length=1024, required=True, placeholder="Grund", style=discord.TextInputStyle.paragraph)
                        self.entbannungsantrag_test = discord.ui.UserSelect(custom_id="Dies ist eine Costum-id", disabled=False ,min_values=1, max_values=2, row=None)
                        self.add_item(self.entbannungsantrag_grund)
                        self.add_item(self.entbannungsantrag_test)
                    async def callback(self, interaction: Interaction) -> None:
                        datenbank.data[f"{interaction.user.id}thema"] = "1"
                        datenbank.data[f"{interaction.user.id}grund"] = self.entbannungsantrag_grund.value
                        datenbank.data[f"{interaction.user.id}user_id"] = interaction.user.id
                        datenbank.data[f"{interaction.user.id}dm_id"] = interaction.channel_id
                        print(datenbank.data[f"{interaction.user.id}thema"])
                        
                        await create_thread ("1", interaction)
                        await send_embed_2(interaction)
```

I have this add to my Modal, but it came over and over the same Error. I´dont know what is mean with  the invaild body